# How do I handle file paths in my code before moving to server host?

Tags: asp.net

In my webpages I have references to js and images as such:
"../../Content/Images/"Filename"

In my code if I reference a file as above, it doesnt work so i have to write:
"c:/miscfiles/"filename"

1-Why does the first reference work on webpages and not within the code?
2-How should i reference file paths in code so that I will not have to recode when moving to server?

Comment: you need to show some code that is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See following for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Don't use absolute paths in development - always use relative paths that are preceded with the application root token (the tilde or `~`) like this:

```
"~/Content/Images/Filename"
```

ASP.NET will convert the `~` to the proper value based on the virtual directory or website the code is hosted in.

Comment: is this supposed to work when saving a file to a directory? Its not.

Comment: Please provide a small, complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET 2.0 onwards, in order to get the tilda (~) syntax to resolve correctly on the server, you have to include a title and a runat attribute as follows:

```
<img src="~/images/image.jpg" title="Image" runat="server" />
```

The presence of the runat attribute ensures that the path is resolved on the server.